# What is Sri Vaishnavism? What is the Vishishtadvaita?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, bhakti

I'm a liberal Vaishnava ... I was formerly practising Gaudiya Vaishnavism but recently got dissatisfied with it as their doctrines about Goloka and Krishna's supremacy based on Rasa concept wasn't working out well for me .. Now I'm fascinated about the traditional Sri Sampradaya ... Can any Sri Vaishnava help me out by introducing me to the Sampradaya ?

Comment: See here... there are many questions related to Sri Vaishnavism.. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sri-vaishnava

Comment: @@Harinarayana Dasa - Nice to hear that you are interested in Sri Vaishnavism.In addition to to the questions on this forum,  I can provide the names of good books which will introduce you to SriVaishnava. Let me know, if you would be interested.

Comment: @@Krishna yes sure .... Im very eager to start learning

Comment: @@Harinarayana Dasa - I have added a few books in the chat room. pls check it out. If you can provide email id , i can send a few more links and book details. You too can simply google and find a plethora of good books on Srivaishnavism in general.